# What OAuth pattern/flow is this called?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to use OAuth 2 in order to create an protected API. Except, I want all of my users on the site to require an `access token` in order for them to access the API.

The reason being is my API will be exposed to the public, but I don't want the public to access this API. My application makes a number of calls to my API via Ajax requests.

Anyway, for example, in my application if a user clicks on another users profile, it will make an ajax request to:

```
example.com/api/user/id
```

And this will return the `json` data about the user.

But, I want them protected so an `access token` is required - even by registered users - to view them.

SoundCloud is doing exactly what I'm attempting to achieve. Every user is authenticated with an OAuth token.

```
1. Login to SoundCloud
2. Issue an OAuth token to the logged in user
3. Use this token to make API requests
```

I'm sure a number of sites are doing this, but I can't find a specific tutorial on putting together this type of `model` as I assume it's a popular model implemented on a number of sites.

What is this pattern called?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that you are referring to "[Client-side JavaScript applications](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#client-side)" in SoundCloud API document. If so, probably the flow is "Implicit Flow". See "[1.3.2. Implicit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2)" and "[4.2. Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)" in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

There is no name for the pattern that you described. In OAuth 2.0 there are different flows for a user to grant a third-party access to their protected resources (called Grant Types), but what you described above does not have a name.